# Divide last by first row of a group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID  Quantity Time
54  100      2020-01-01 00:00:05
54  87       2020-01-01 00:00:06
58  400      2020-01-01 00:00:08
58  390      2020-01-01 00:00:14
...
```

I already grouped the dataframe by ID and took only the first and the last value for each ID.

```
g = df.groupby('ID')

(pd.concat([g.head(1), g.tail(1)])
   .drop_duplicates()
   .sort_values('ID')
   .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Now, I would like to divide the quantity of the last row of each ID by the quantity of the first row and save it to the column "Result" for only the last entry.

The resulting df should look like this:

```
ID  Quantity  Time                  Result
54  100       2020-01-01 00:00:05   
54  87        2020-01-01 00:00:06   0.87
58  400       2020-01-01 00:00:08
58  390       2020-01-01 00:00:14   0.975
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

If there is always pairs `ID` you can select all pair rows by indexing `[1::2]` and divide by shifted values by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['Result'] = df['Quantity'].iloc[1::2].div(df['Quantity'].shift())
print (df)
   ID  Quantity                 Time  Result
0  54       100  2020-01-01 00:00:05     NaN
1  54        87  2020-01-01 00:00:06   0.870
2  58       400  2020-01-01 00:00:08     NaN
3  58       390  2020-01-01 00:00:14   0.975
```

Solution working with groups:

Another idea is use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and divide by last value per `ID` by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
first = df.groupby('ID')['Quantity'].transform('first')
df['Result'] = df.drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')['Quantity'].div(first)
print (df)
   ID  Quantity                 Time  Result
0  54       100  2020-01-01 00:00:05     NaN
1  54        87  2020-01-01 00:00:06   0.870
2  58       400  2020-01-01 00:00:08     NaN
3  58       390  2020-01-01 00:00:14   0.975
```

Or use lambda function with replace by `NaN` by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Result'] = (df.groupby('ID')['Quantity'].transform(lambda x: x.iat[-1] / x.iat[0])
                  .mask(df['ID'].duplicated(keep='last')))
print (df)

   ID  Quantity                 Time  Result
0  54       100  2020-01-01 00:00:05     NaN
1  54        87  2020-01-01 00:00:06   0.870
2  58       400  2020-01-01 00:00:08     NaN
3  58       390  2020-01-01 00:00:14   0.975
```

Whats happen if a least one group with unique `ID`?

```
print (df)
   ID  Quantity                 Time
0  54       100  2020-01-01 00:00:05
1  58       400  2020-01-01 00:00:08
2  58       390  2020-01-01 00:00:14

#failed
df['Result1'] = df['Quantity'].iloc[1::2].div(df['Quantity'].shift())
#working correct
first = df.groupby('ID')['Quantity'].transform('first')
df['Result2'] = df.drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')['Quantity'].div(first)
#working correct
df['Result3'] = (df.groupby('ID')['Quantity'].transform(lambda x: x.iat[-1] / x.iat[0])
                  .mask(df['ID'].duplicated(keep='last')))
print (df)
   ID  Quantity                 Time  Result1  Result2  Result3
0  54       100  2020-01-01 00:00:05      NaN    1.000    1.000
1  58       400  2020-01-01 00:00:08      4.0      NaN      NaN
2  58       390  2020-01-01 00:00:14      NaN    0.975    0.975
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Could you maybe explain what the iloc[1::2] and the shift() are doing?

Comment: @Michelle - Sure, `iloc[1::2]` seelct only pair columns, it means second for each `ID` and shift is used for shifting up to one row values of column.

Answer (score 1):

You could chunk into a couple of steps :

Create a grouping :

```
grouping = df.groupby("ID", sort=False).Quantity
```

Divide the last by the first per `ID`:

```
first_div_last = grouping.last().div(grouping.first()).array
```

Get a boolean for the last row for each `ID`:

```
last_rows = df.Quantity.eq(grouping.transform("last"))
```

Assign the result to a new column in df :

```
df.loc[last_rows, "Result"] = first_div_last

df

    ID  Quantity    Time       Result
0   54  100 2020-01-01 00:00:05 NaN
1   54  87  2020-01-01 00:00:06 0.870
2   58  400 2020-01-01 00:00:08 NaN
3   58  390 2020-01-01 00:00:14 0.975
```